# rule for textarea in model class in Yii

Tags: model, yii, xss, validation

I have Active Record model for a table in Yii framework.
And have a textarea in a form for one field of this table.

What rule Can I set for it in rules function of model class to be secure from XSS attackes ?

Comment: XSS prevention is not about blacklisting bad input, it's about escaping bad (according to the context) output. A validation rule is the wrong place to worry about this, the right place is the output: use `htmlspecialchars` to escape the content of this textarea when displaying it on a webpage and other corresponding functions when displaying it in other contexts.

Comment: Thank you DCoder. I know what you say. I don't know how it is in Yii. I am just start learning yii.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow "normal" PHP security procedures to prevent an XSS attack. But have a look at the following posts on Yii security:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/273/yii-security-extended-guide/
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.security